# Can INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE cause issue with release version?

Tags: android

Recently I updated my windows (from 8.1 to 10). After working on my app that I used to debug on 8.1, when I try to run from w10, I get `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE`. Now **I assume** this is caused by different fingerprint of new Windows version, the debug version was signed by previous one and they dont match.

*My question is* : can this cause problem when building a release version too? Will the data of my users be wiped by this **or** the keystore will take care of that (because they release keystore didnt change therefore on deployed devices it wont complain)?

Comment: Have you changed build targets since changing from Windows 8.1 to 10, or any other project modifications that might be to blame? I'm a bit confused why the debug key would have changed, it's dangerous to just assume that's the problem.

Comment: I did full reformat of hdd for clean install. When I installed adb drivers for my phone, it showed me the fingerprint and asked if I want to allow debugging which it only does when already saved fingerprint doesnt match. Thats why I assume thats the issue. I did change build tools from 23 to 23.0.1, but that shouldnt trigger this warning I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using the same release keystore, then the release version will work to upgrade the current application, and no data will be lost. If the keystore changes, you cannot upgrade the application, and any new version would require a complete uninstall of the old one.

Also, if your application is on the Play Store, you would not be able to upload the APK anyway if the keystore did not match, so the error will be caught before it gets to users.

Comment: Perfect, thats what i was looking for. Wasnt sure if keystore takes care of everything, but it just makes logical sense it does.